FIML in 2-level svyglm / svylm?
I am learning data analysis in R so please let me know if this is a weird question.
I am analyzing an complex survey data using the survey package. I would also want my model to be 2-level, meaning that one of my variables is at the cluster level. I came across this Full Information Maximum Likelihood (FIML) method and thought it would be nice to use it for missing data handling in my analysis. However, when I dig into it, I found out that the lavaan package (usually used regarding FIML) is for SEM. I was wondering if there is a way to do something like svyglm or svylm using the FIML method on a complex survey?
Or, can I do logistic or linear model using lavaan package? I am also new to SEM and I fear that it may have too much additional assumptions that I don't need.
In case it is important - my outcome (dependent) variable can be dicotomous or continuous (0-5 integers), so either logistic or linear model would do.

hi, there's a survey-adjusted SEM R package but not sure if it's maintained since it's been removed from cran?

@AnthonyDamico Hi, Thank you so much for replying. I thought the lavaan.survey package is also for SEM but just with the survey adjustment? I guess my question would be if an SEM model can do the same thing as a logistic or linear model, and not adding too many assumptions?
